# php return from ajax call is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, return

i call the php function with ajax but my return from my php function is empty ?

this is my ajax call :

```
    showEvent : function(eventId){

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: "routing.php?page=Events&action=showEvent",
            data : {event_id :eventId},
            dataType : "text",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#showEvent').modal("show");
                $('#showClickedEvent').children("tr").val("test");
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,e){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

and hier my php function :

```
function call($page,$action){

    require_once("Controller/".$page."Controller.php");
    $request = array_merge($_GET,$_POST);

    switch($page)
    {
        case "Index":
            switch($action)
            {
                case "home":
                    return IndexController::home();
                break;

                case "login":
                    return IndexController::login();
                break;
            }
        case "Events":
            switch($action)
            {
                case "createEvent":
                    return EventsController::createEvent();
                break;

                case "setEvent":
                    EventsService::setEvent($request["homepartyName"],$request["date"],$request["musicDirection"],
                        $request["ageFrom"],$request["ageTo"],$request["maxPersons"],$request["country"],$request["city"],$_COOKIE["facebook_id"]);
                    break;

                case "showEvents":

                break;

                case "myEvents":
                    return EventsController::myEvents();
                break;

                case "showEvent":
                    return EventsService::getEvent($request["event_id"]);
                break;

            }
        case "User":
            switch($action)
            {
                case "createUser":
                    UserService::setUser($request["facebookData"]);
                    break;

                case "logoutUser":
                    UserController::logoutUser();
                    break;
            }

    }
}
```

this method is calling by my Eventservice :

```
public static function getEvent($id){

    $db = parent::getInstance();
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = ".$id."";

    $event = $db->query($stmt)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) or die($db->error);

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    return json_encode($event);
}
```

i don't know why  the return is empty :/

Comment: PHP needs to echo the JSON.

Comment: Is the 'id' field an integer? Try echoing out the sql statement and running directly in your db to make sure you get expected results.

Comment: You need to `echo` the return value as a string to the responseText. Simply calling `return` won't have any effect.

Comment: sir in **url: "routing.php?page=Events&action=showEvent",** the function in php named call($page,$action) is not call

Comment: the function **call($page,$action)** call from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change **dataType:'JSON'** in ajax function because we are trying to get JSON from ajax response instead of text.

Also use **exit(json_encode($event))** instead of **return json_encode($event)** to get the proper json response.